# How can I detect a paletted PNG file?

Tags: php, node.js, imagemagick, png

I would like to have a function which returns `true` when presented with a PNG file such as the following:

[image]

and `false` when presented with a "natural" PNG, such as a photograph, or anything *other* than an PNG which is simply a dump of a progression of colours, like the one presented in this question.

> But what have you tried?

I have tried nothing. I have one or two ideas, such as randomly sampling horizontal and vertical strips of pixels and looking for perfectly linear chrominance changes, but I ask here because I want to involve the HiveMind for better insight, and because I know most problems have a **very simple** solution.

I would prefer the solution to be in JavaScript (think NodeJS with ImageMagick) or in PHP (with Imagick). That said, any language will do, provided the algorithm is solid.

Thanking y'all in advance

Comment: The question title does not agree with the body: a "paletted" image is that which includes a palette of colours (up to 256 colors normally), but you want a different thing. Further, the thing you want is a feature of the raw image, it has nothing to do with its encoding (PNG, JPG BMP or whatever). Finally, a "dump of progression of colours" is a fuzzy concept, so at best one could propose some heuristic, never a "solid" algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Just peek at the "color_type" byte in the file.  If it's 3 the PNG is paletted, otherwise it isn't.  The color_type byte is byte 25 (after the 8-byte signature that begins at byte 0, 4-byte length, 4-byte "IHDR" chunk name, 4-byte width, 4-byte height, and 1-byte bit_depth).
See the PNG specification at www.w3.org/TR/REC-png

As @leonbloy commented, though, your example PNG is not paletted.  It's color type 2
and has a lot more than 256 colors.

If you are really trying to distinguish between "natural" images (e.g., photos) and graphic art, rather than the PNG color type, you could check the compression ratio (ratio of uncompressed to compressed; the uncompressed is width*height*pixel_size, and compressed is the size of the file you are checking).  Natural images don't compress very well as PNGs. To eliminate metadata from this calculation, use total IDAT size instead of file size.

Or, just convert the image to PNG and JPEG.  If the resulting PNG is larger than the JPEG, it's natural.  If the PNG is smaller than the JPEG, it's graphic art.  With your sample image, using ImageMagick,

```
convert 1T5aQ.png png:- | wc -c
  59872
convert 1T5aQ.png jpg:- | wc -c
  703739
```

The PNG is less than 1/10th of the size of the JPEG, so it's graphic art.